# jshell (Java 9 shell) integration does not respond in SublimeREPL

Tags: java, sublimetext3, sublimerepl, jshell

I have tried to integrate the `jshell` Java 9 REPL into SublimeREPL as described in [this documentation](https://sublimerepl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#frequently-asked-questions). I have set up the files correctly:

[image]

When I run the REPL from Sublime, I get the initial output generated by the REPL, so I know it is able to access the `jshell` executable:

[image]

However, the SublimeREPL interface seems to not be sending my input upon hitting `Enter` to the REPL, as I am getting no response back upon attempting to submit an expression to the REPL:

[image]

Any assistance on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated. I have exhausted my list of potential fixes.